# How to modify C# 4.5 WPF webbrowser element before start rendering

Tags: c#, wpf, browser, webbrowser-control, dom-events

I want to inject Javascript code just below the head element.
For example below code:

```
<script src="C:\jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {           
        alert('all successfull');
    });

</script>
```

It has to be done before webbrowser object start rendering page. Otherwise script would not be loaded.

Now I have come so far like below but can not find a way to inject this below script. Help is appreciated.

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        wbScreen1.LoadCompleted += wbScreen1_LoadCompleted;
        wbScreen1.Navigate("http://www.monstermmorpg.com");
    }

    void wbScreen1_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

C# 5 , WPF application

Comment: how about proxy, intercept request and inject script before sending it to webbrowser; fiddler can be used for that